# android app to send image via email fails with file not found or permissions

Tags: android, image, email-attachments

I am creating an android app to send an email with attached image.
The mail arrives with no attachment.
I have tried three ways to create the file. and two ways to send.
the code returns exception "filenotfound" or some permission error.
Below is an extraction of the code.

```
manifest has:
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 
 private File storeImage(Bitmap image) {
        File pic = new File("picdefulet.png");
        String filename = "pic.png";
        try {
            switch (1) {
                case 1:
                    pic = new
                            File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                            filename);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    try {
                        File dirFile = getCacheDir();
                        boolean result = dirFile.mkdir();
                        pic = new File(getCacheDir(), filename);
                    } catch( Exception e){
                        Log.e("BROKEN", e.getMessage());
                    }
                break;
                case 3:
                    pic = new File(filename);
                default:
                    break;
            }
            try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pic);
            boolean result = image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            } catch( Exception e){
                Log.e("BROKEN", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("BROKEN", e.getMessage());
        }
        return pic;
    } // end storeImage

    String msgtext = "#22 Please warn/fine/terminate the user \\n\\n";
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        File fileThing = storeImage(photo);
         
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("multipart/alternative;");
        String[] recipient = new String[2];
        recipient[0] = "roySpin@royweil.com";
        recipient[1] =  "roysoin2@royweil.com";
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,recipient); // recipients
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Scooter Illegaly Parked");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msgtext);
        if (!fileThing.getPath().isEmpty()) {
        switch (1) {
       case 1:
      Uri pngUri = Uri.parse("file//" + fileThing);
      break;
       case 2:
                Uri pngUri = Uri.fromFile ( fileThing);
      break;
   }
        mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pngUri);
        gtartActivity(emailIntent);
```

Comment: `Uri.parse("file//" + fileThing)` is an invalid `Uri` -- you would need `file://`. That would give you the same result as `Uri.fromFile ( fileThing)`, which has been unusable for five years. Please use `FileProvider` and `getUriForFile()` to make your content available to other apps.

Comment: I am a newbie to Android development. . Any chance you could point me to a code example that uses FileProvider and getUriForFile in an email attachment context?

Comment: trying 
```
    pngUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
          getApplicationContext(),
          getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider",
          fileThing);
```
I get:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.example.spinillegalyparked.provider

Comment: Add  a provider and an xml file.
```
Getting error on start up

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.spinillegalyparked, PID: 7172
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.spinillegalyparked/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes4.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~tmJ4jyTAEe0vdZl2I8vtkg==/com.example.spinillegalyparked-...

Comment: ```
<provider
          android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider"
     android:exported="false"
     android:grantUriPermissions="true">
     <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>

Comment: "Any chance you could point me to a code example that uses FileProvider and getUriForFile in an email attachment context?" -- not in Java. [This Kotlin sample](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-andexplore/-/tree/v2.2/T30-Share) uses `FileProvider` with `ACTION_SEND`.